# Form input change to white background - iphone 6

Tags: forms, input, iphone-6

I have a form. When i type first character in iphone 6 all form and input change to white background (font color also white too), i can't do anything with it. When delete all character in input. Form change to normal. It works in firefox, chrome, safari and android except iphone. Anyone can help me please. Thank you so much!

Update form css:

```
 background-color: #f2f2f2;
 padding: 10px 10px 10px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 max-width: 550px;
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 0px rgba(217,217,217,1);
```

I just try `background: transparent; background: none; all: revert !important;` with input but nothing work for me.

[image: The form look like this]

Comment: Please go read [ask], and how to create a [mcve].

Comment: Because it was a low-quality question containing not nearly enough information to reproduce the problem (barely _any_ useful info at all.) And just dropping a few lines of CSS here now, is still miles away from a proper MCVE.

Comment: it still in update bro. tks for remind me

Answer (score -1, accepted):

fix this bug.

```
    input {
       position: relative;
       z-index: 10;
       display: block;
    }
```